# Regular expression for Swift X character set in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

As per the [swift](https://www.paiementor.com/swift-formatting-rules-and-character-sets-of-mt-messages/#xcharsets) documentation, The SWIFT X character set consists of the below

**X Character Set – SWIFT Character Set**

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
/ – ? : ( ) . , ‘ + CrLf Space
```

I have come up with the below to validate the swift character set which seems to be working but want to know if there is a better way of doing it.Also what should I use for CRLF to be OS neutral.Since i use unix I have put chr(10)

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 -?:().,''+chr(10)/]*$
```

Comment: You "come up with the below" in order to solve what problem? You forgot to tell us what the task is.

Comment: In any case, note that the meaning of a range like `a-z` depends on language settings; it may include accented letters, for example (which you don't want to include).

Comment: The task is to validate special characters for field 20,21 in MT 202 in SWift messages

Comment: it has to be only english characters not accented letters ,then how do i modify the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, a range like `a-z` may include accented letters and collation elements, depending on the value of `nls_sort` at the time of running a query. And, alas, Oracle does not support the character class `[[:ascii:]]`, which would be another way to specify what you need.

You have two choices. Either you specify the `nls_sort` parameter explicitly every time, before running the query (or rely on it being something like `'English'` already), which to me doesn't sound like a good practice; or you specify all letters explicitly.

There are a few more things to fix. The dash `-` has special meaning in a bracketed expression; if you want it to mean a literal dash, it should appear as either the first or the last character in the list, where it can't have its special meaning. All other regexp special characters are **not** special in a bracketed expression, so you don't need to worry about dot, question mark, asterisk, parentheses, etc.

However, note that the single-quote character, while it has no special meaning in a regular expression (in a bracketed expression or otherwise), it ***does*** have a special meaning in a string in Oracle; to include a single-quote in a hard-coded string, you must escape it by typing **two** single-quote characters.

Then - if you write `chr(10)` in a bracketed expression, that is characters `c`, `h`, ... - if you mean LF, you need to either actually include a newline character in your string (probably a bad idea), or concatenate it by hand.

And if you want to validate against the official character set of "swift x" (whatever that is), you should include all characters, regardless of your OS. So you should accept CR (chr(13)) too, unless you have a better reason to omit it. If it is present but you don't want it in your db, you should accept it and then remove it after the fact and save the resulting string (after you remove CR), not reject the entire string altogether.

To keep the work organized, I would create a very small table (or view) to store the needed validation string, then use it in all queries that need it.

Something like this:

```
create table swift_validation (validation_pattern varchar2(100));

insert into swift_validation (validation_pattern)
  with helper(ascii_letters) as (
    select 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' from dual
  )
  select '^[' || ascii_letters             --  a-z (ASCII)
              || upper(ascii_letters)      --  A-Z (ASCII)
              || '0-9'
              || chr(10) || chr(13)        --  LF and CR
              || '/?:().,''+ -'
              || ']*$'
  from   helper
;

commit;
```

Check what was saved in the table:

```
select * from swift_validation;

VALIDATION_PATTERN                                          
------------------------------------------------------------
^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0-9

/?:().,'+ -]*$
```

Note that the result is in three lines. `chr(10)` is seen as a newline; then `chr(13)` by itself is converted to another newline.

In any case, if you really want to see the exact characters saved in this string, you can use the `dump` function. With option `17` for the second argument, the output is readable (you will have to scroll though):

```
select dump(validation_pattern, 17) from swift_validation;

DUMP(VALIDATION_PATTERN,17)                                                                                                                                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=73: ^,[,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,0,-,9,^J,^M,/,?,:,(,),.,,,',+, ,-,],*,$
```

Notice in particular the control characters, `^J` and `^M`; they mean `chr(10)` and `chr(13)` respectively (easy to remember: J and M are the tenth and thirteenth letters of the Latin alphabet).

Then you use this as follows:

```
with
  test_strings (str) as (
    select 'abc + (12)'    from dual union all
    select '$122.38'       from dual union all
    select null            from dual union all
    select 'café au lait'  from dual union all
    select 'A / B - C * D' from dual
  )
select t.str,
       case when regexp_like(t.str, sv.validation_pattern)
            then 'valid' else 'invalid' end as swift_valid
from   test_strings t, swift_validation sv
;

STR            SWIFT_VALID
-------------  -----------
abc + (12)     valid  
$122.38        invalid
               invalid
café au lait   invalid
A / B - C * D  invalid
```

Notice one last oddity here. In my test, I included a row where the input string is empty (`null`). Regular expressions are odd in this respect: `null` is **not** (regexp_) like something like `'a*'` - even though `*` is supposed to mean "zero or more ...". Oracle's reasoning, perhaps, is that `null` may be anything - just one of the hundreds of ways the Oracle identification of `null` and "empty string" is just plain idiotic. It is what it is though; make sure you don't reject a row with an empty string. I assume "swift x" allows empty strings. You will need to handle that separately, like this:

```
with
  test_strings (str) as (
    select 'abc + (12)'    from dual union all
    select '$122.38'       from dual union all
    select null            from dual union all
    select 'café au lait'  from dual union all
    select 'A / B - C * D' from dual
  )
select t.str,
       case when t.str is null
              or regexp_like(t.str, sv.validation_pattern)
            then 'valid' else 'invalid' end as swift_valid
from   test_strings t, swift_validation sv
;

STR            SWIFT_VALID
-------------  -----------
abc + (12)     valid  
$122.38        invalid
               valid
café au lait   invalid
A / B - C * D  invalid
```

**Left as exercise**:

You may need to find the invalid characters in an invalid string. For such generalized applications (more than a straight validation of a whole string), you might be better off saving just the bracketed expression in the `swift_validation` table (without the leading anchor `^`, and the trailing quantifier `*` and anchor `$`). Then you need to re-write the validation query slightly, to concatenate these fragments to the validation pattern in the `regexp_like` condition; but then you can include, for example, an additional column to show the first invalid character in an invalid string.

**EDIT**

In follow-up discussion (see comments below this answer), the OP clarified that only the combination `chr(13) || chr(10)` (in that order) is permitted. `chr(10)` and `chr(13)` are invalid if they appear by themselves, or in the wrong order.

This makes the problem more interesting (more complicated). To allow only the letters a, b, c or the sequence xy (that is: x alone, or y alone, are not allowed; every x must appear followed immediately by y, and every y must appear immediately preceded by x), the proper matching pattern looks like

```
'^([abc]|xy)*$'
```

Here `expr1|expr2` is alternation, and it needs to be enclosed in parentheses to apply the `*` quantifier.

An additional complication is that `$` doesn't actually match "the end of the input string"; it anchors either at the end of the input string, **or** if the input string ends in newline (`chr(10)`), it anchors **before** that character. Happily, there is the alternative anchor `\z` that doesn't suffer from that defect; it anchors truly at the end of the input string. This will be needed if we don't want to validate input strings that end in `chr(10)` not preceded immediately by `chr(13)`. (If we do want to allow those - even though technically they do violate the "swift x" rules - then replace `\z` with `$` as we had it before).

Here I demonstrate a slightly modified approach - now the small table that stores the validation rule only contains the alternation bit - either one character out of an enumeration, *or* the two-character sequence `chr(13) || chr(10)`), letting the "caller" wrap this within whatever is needed for a complete matching pattern.

The small table (note that I changed the column name):

```
drop table swift_validation purge;

create table swift_validation (valid_patterns varchar2(100));

insert into swift_validation (valid_patterns)
  with helper(ascii_letters) as (
    select 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' from dual
  )
  select    '['                           -- open bracketed expression
                || ascii_letters          --  a-z (ASCII)
                || upper(ascii_letters)   --  A-Z (ASCII)
                || '0-9'
                || '/?:().,''+ -'         --  '' escape for ', - last
         || ']'                           -- close bracketed expression
         || '|'                           -- alternation
                || chr(13) || chr(10)     --  CR LF
  from   helper
;

commit;
```

Testing (notice the modified match pattern: now the `^` and `\z` anchors, the parentheses and the `*` quantifier are hard-coded in the query, not in the saved string):

```
with
  test_strings (id, str) as (
    select 1, 'abc + (12)'                from dual union all
    select 2, '$122.38'                   from dual union all
    select 3, null                        from dual union all
    select 4, 'no_underline'              from dual union all
    select 5, 'A / B - C * D'             from dual union all
    select 6, 'abc' || chr(10) || chr(13) from dual union all
    select 7, 'abc' || chr(10)            from dual union all
    select 8, 'abc' || chr(13) || chr(10) from dual union all
    select 9, 'café au lait'              from dual
  )
select t.id, t.str,
       case when t.str is null
              or regexp_like(t.str, '^(' || sv.valid_patterns || ')*\z')
            then 'valid' else 'invalid' end as swift_valid
from   test_strings t, swift_validation sv
;

ID  STR            SWIFT_VALID
--  -------------  -----------
 1  abc + (12)     valid      
 2  $122.38        invalid    
 3                 valid      
 4  no_underline   invalid    
 5  A / B - C * D  invalid    
 6  abc            invalid    
    
                           
 
 7  abc            invalid    
 
 8  abc            valid      

 9  café au lait   invalid
```

The newline characters (CR and LF) aren't clearly visible in the output; I added an `id` column so you can reference the output according to the input in the `with` clause.

Comment: The answer is perfect only requirement is it should be CRLF and not LFCR which I have not mentioned.hence it is just for information

Comment: @psaraj12 - Those are separate characters, the order does not matter. They don't even need to be consecutive. If you must check that CR never appears alone, and is always followed immediately by LF, that is a different kind of question.

Comment: this is given in documentation The characters Cr and Lf must never be used as single characters and must only be used together in the sequence CrLf, that is, LfCr is not allowed

Comment: any idea what it means

Comment: @psaraj12 - Yes; II will edit the answer to show how to cover this case. It will be along the lines of the "exercise" I left at the end.

Comment: I will test it and get back with the results

Comment: it is working as expected